# How can I see which garbage collector java is using

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The Java Virtual Machine supports several garbage collection strategies.

This [article](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html) explains them.

Now I am wondering which (automatically selected) strategy my application is using, is there any way to let the JVM(version 1.6) print this information?

Edit: The JVM detects if it is in client or server mode. So the question really is how can I see which has been detected?

Comment: Note that the article talks about **one specific implementation** (specifically the HotSpot JVM from the Sun JRE).

Comment: Please note that you are not necessarily using just one GC. You typically have different strategies for different areas. If you use CMS I think the default is to use a the "new parallel" for the young area.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html which is applicable for J2SE 6 as well states that the default is the Parallel Collector.

We tested this once on a JVM 1.5 by setting only

```
-server -Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=4m -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

and the output showed

```
41359.597: [GC [PSYoungGen: 90499K->32K(377344K)] 268466K->181862K(2474496K), 0.0183138 secs]
41359.615: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 32K->0K(377344K)] [PSOldGen: 181830K->129760K(2097152K)] 181862K->129760K(2474496K) [PSPermGen: 115335K->115335K(131072K)], 4.4590942 secs]
```

where PS stands for Parallel Scavenging

Answer (score 18):

`jmap -heap`

Prints a heap summary. GC algorithm used, heap configuration and generation wise heap usage are printed.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html

Comment: This is precisely what I need, unfortunately it isn't available on Windows (no clue why though).

Comment: Maybe you should add that information (Windows) to the question ;)

Answer (score 9):

Put this in the JAVA_OPTS:

```
-XX:+UseSerialGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

For the **UseSerialGC** we will see in the log:

```
 7.732: [GC 7.732: [DefNew: 419456K->47174K(471872K), 0.1321800 secs] 419456K->47174K(1520448K), 0.1322500 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.03, real=0.14 secs]
```

For the **UseConcMarkSweepGC** we will see in the log:

```
 5.630: [GC 5.630: ['ParNew: 37915K->3941K(38336K), 0.0123210 secs] 78169K->45163K(1568640K), 0.0124030 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

For the **UseParallelGC** we will see in the log:

```
30.250: [GC [PSYoungGen: 441062K->65524K(458752K)] 441062K->76129K(1507328K), 0.1870880 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.03, real=0.19 secs]
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like, we have more convenient way to define the version of `GC` at runtime. Always use tools, my suggestion.
To define GC version we need two tools that come with JVM (placed in your `jdk/bin` directory):

1. `VisualVM` - start it and try to profile some process (for example you can profile VisualVM itself). Your profile will show you a **PID** of process (see the green rectangles at a screenshot).
2. `jMap` - start this tool with `-heap <PID>` options and find a string dedicated to a Garbage Collector type (see a pink line at a screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As Joachim already pointed out, the article you refer to describes the VM strategies offered by Sun's VM. The VM specification itself does not mandate specific GC algorithms and hence it won't make sense to have e.g. enumerated values for these in the API.

You can however get some infos from the Management API:

```
List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> beans = 
    ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
```

Iterating through these beans, you can get the name of the GC (although only as a string) and the names of the memory pools, which are managed by the different GCs.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to get this is :
Go to command Line and enter the following command.

java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version

It will show you result like :

```
C:\windows\system32>java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=132968640 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2127498240 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFl
ags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseLargePagesInd
**ividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC**
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple progam which connects via jmx to your java process:

```
public class PrintJMX {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String rmiHostname = "localhost";
    String defaultUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + rmiHostname + ":1099/jmxrmi";
    JMXServiceURL jmxServiceURL = new JMXServiceURL(defaultUrl);

    JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxServiceURL);
    MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();


    ObjectName gcName = new ObjectName(ManagementFactory.GARBAGE_COLLECTOR_MXBEAN_DOMAIN_TYPE + ",*");

    for (ObjectName name : mbsc.queryNames(gcName, null)) {
      GarbageCollectorMXBean gc = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(mbsc,
        name.getCanonicalName(),
        GarbageCollectorMXBean.class);

      System.out.println(gc.getName());
    }

  }
}
```