# How can I find out at runtime what garbage collection algorithm is configured in my JVM?

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

I have an instance of Tomcat 6.0.18 running on Sun's Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM build 1.6.0_14-b08.  Is there any way for me to find out what garbage collection algorithm the JVM is using to run my web application?

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498942/how-can-i-see-which-garbage-collector-java-is-using

Answer (score 1):

You can print out JVM garbage collection information by using the `-verbose:gc` VM argument. This will at least let you know when . You can use jstat to get detailed information as shown here http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstat-gcutil-Garbage-Collection-Statistics.html. This Sun (or Oracle) page has a whole bunch of garbage collection info http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JDK's JVisualVM it lists the GC algo.