# In Java how can I find which garbage collector a process is using at run-time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In Java how can I find which garbage collector I'm using at run-time?

So I can print Using "Garbage-First Collector" in my log files.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer, but try looking at the memory-related MBeans.

Comment: Use visualvm or jconsole.

Comment: @GregKopff Already noted and deleted the comment.

Comment: @Aniket Thakur: how using visualjvm ? i can't see the data - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using this  **ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()**

```
List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> beans = 
    ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
```

for more details

[use this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the standard JVM MBeans.  Specifically: `sun.management.GarbageCollectorImpl`.

[This page](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jmx/list-all-jvm-mbeans/) suggests that you'll be able to obtain this information:

```
Class Name: sun.management.GarbageCollectorImpl
Object Name: java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Copy
```

Comment: The linked duplicate question has this similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2499524/1212960