# How to check which GC a JVM is using?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I have server (oracle/sun) JVM running, how do I check which GC it uses at runtime? Eg, if it is using UseG1GC UseConcMarkSweepGC. (jdk is 1.7_79)

I know I can use the `jinfo <pid>` to check the VM Flags from the output. But what if the JVM is started without these parameters.

I can't find this info in `jvisualvm` either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498942/how-can-i-see-which-garbage-collector-java-is-using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use JMap.

jMap - start this tool with -heap  options and find a string dedicated to a Garbage Collector type. like

```
$ jmap -heap 30166
Attaching to process ID 30166, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.80-b11

using parallel threads in the new generation.
using thread-local object allocation.
Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 4294967296 (4096.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1431633920 (1365.3125MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 1431633920 (1365.3125MB)
   OldSize          = 2863267840 (2730.625MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 85983232 (82.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 1288503296 (1228.8125MB)
   used     = 339354840 (323.63399505615234MB)
   free     = 949148456 (905.1785049438477MB)
   26.337134026236903% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 1145372672 (1092.3125MB)
   used     = 313863536 (299.32359313964844MB)
   free     = 831509136 (792.9889068603516MB)
   27.402743550005006% used
From Space:
   capacity = 143130624 (136.5MB)
   used     = 25491304 (24.310401916503906MB)
   free     = 117639320 (112.1895980834961MB)
   17.809818253849016% used
To Space:
   capacity = 143130624 (136.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 143130624 (136.5MB)
   0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 2863333376 (2730.6875MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 2863333376 (2730.6875MB)
   0.0% used
Perm Generation:
   capacity = 23920640 (22.8125MB)
   used     = 23801432 (22.698814392089844MB)
   free     = 119208 (0.11368560791015625MB)
   99.5016521297089% used

10243 interned Strings occupying 814216 bytes.
```